# PHP 7.0 SoapClient on Debian 9 gives error randomly

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am connecting to a SOAPServer using an https WSDL uri which gives errors once out of 10 or 15 attempts. I am connecting to this SOAP uri once every 5 minutes. I am occasionally getting the below errors randomly.

- Error Fetching http headers
- SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://..
- Error Fetching http body, No Content-Length, connection closed or chunked data
- Could not connect to host

It is randomly generating all the above errors. Given below is my configuration

```
 ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 180);
 ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
 ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

 return new SoapClient($url,array(
  'trace' => 1,
  'exceptions' => true,
  'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  'keep_alive' => true,
  'connection_timeout' => 180,
  'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
          [
             'ssl' => [
                 'verify_peer'       => false,
                 'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                 'allow_self_signed' => true
             ]
          ]
      )
 ));
```

Comment: The variable $url does contain the remote WDSL?

Comment: yes. It is the endpoint to an external WSDL

Comment: It is possible that at some point there is a connection error getting the WSDL data. From my experience it can be usefull getting the wsdl, save it locally, and then pass the local file to your SOAP.

This is easily done if the remote WSDL does not have any relative references ( usually XSD definitions ), otherwise you should download everything and it can be complicated.

Can you give it a try?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately WSDL I have contains XSD definitions. As said by the provider, it seems to changing quite often